# nvrtc.nvrtcCompileProgram is changing the output of locale.getpreferredencoding... How can I reset it to its default value?

Tags: python, linux, utf-8, cuda, locale

I am coping with an interesting side effect while using the [`cuda-python`](https://pypi.org/project/cuda-python/) interface.

More in detail, I found out that calling `nvrtc.nvrtcCompileProgram` changes the return value of `locale.getpreferredencoding` from `UTF-8` to `ANSI_X3.4-1968` on my system.
This is quite annoying as it has a side-effects on the `open` function's default behavior,  easily leading to `UnicodeDecodeError`s when using other libraries.

The following code should reproduce the issue, it is a very simple CUDA program that sums two arrays, A and B, and saves the results in C.

```py
import numpy as np 
from cuda import cuda, nvrtc
import locale

# interesting interaction between CUDA and OpenCL

# --- define a simple kernel
kernel_code = """
extern "C" __global__ void array_sum(float *A, float *B, float *C, size_t size, size_t n_threads)
{
    size_t tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    for(size_t i = tid; i<size; i = i + n_threads){
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];   
    }
}
"""

def cuda_check(err): # fun to control for errors from CUDA/NVRTC
    if isinstance(err, cuda.CUresult):
        if err != cuda.CUresult.CUDA_SUCCESS:
            raise RuntimeError("Cuda Error: {}".format(cuda.cuGetErrorString(err)))
    elif isinstance(err, nvrtc.nvrtcResult):
        if err != nvrtc.nvrtcResult.NVRTC_SUCCESS:
            raise RuntimeError("Nvrtc Error: {}".format(nvrtc.nvrtcGetErrorString(err)))
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Unknown error type: {}".format(cuda.cuGetErrorString(err)))

### --- initialization --- ###

# --- create 
err, prog = nvrtc.nvrtcCreateProgram(str.encode(kernel_code, encoding='UTF-8'), b"rendering_kernel.cu", 0, [], [])
cuda_check(err)
# --- compile
print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))      # < ----------- printing preferred locale before
err, = nvrtc.nvrtcCompileProgram(prog, 0, [])
print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))      # < ----------- and after compiling
cuda_check(err)
err, ptx_size = nvrtc.nvrtcGetPTXSize(prog)
print(f'compilation of NVRTC successful, ptx size {ptx_size}')
ptx = b" " * ptx_size
err, = nvrtc.nvrtcGetPTX(prog, ptx) # PTX is here
cuda_check(err)

# initialize CUDA (single GPU)

# Initialize CUDA Driver API
err, = cuda.cuInit(0)
cuda_check(err)

# Retrieve handle for device 0
err, cuDevice = cuda.cuDeviceGet(0)
cuda_check(err)

# Create context
err, context = cuda.cuCtxCreate(0, cuDevice)   
cuda_check(err) 

# # Load PTX as module data and retrieve function
ptx = np.char.array(ptx)
# Note: Incompatible --gpu-architecture would be detected here
err, module = cuda.cuModuleLoadData(ptx.ctypes.data)
cuda_check(err)
err, kernel = cuda.cuModuleGetFunction(module, b"array_sum")
cuda_check(err)

PROGRAM = prog
NUM_THREADS = 2
NUM_BLOCKS = 2
CONTEXT = context
MODULE = module
KERNEL = kernel

err, stream = cuda.cuStreamCreate(0)
cuda_check(err)

### --- END of initialization --- ###

### --- preparing parameters --- ###

# --- PARAMETERS ---    

def byte_size(x):
    return x.size*x.itemsize

def push_to_stream(np_array, stream):
    err, cls = cuda.cuMemAlloc(byte_size(np_array))
    cuda_check(err)
    err, = cuda.cuMemcpyHtoDAsync(
        cls, np_array.ctypes.data, byte_size(np_array), stream
    )
    cuda_check(err)
    return cls

A = np.array([i for i in range(10)], dtype=np.float32)
B = np.array([9-i for i in range(10)], dtype=np.float32)

print(f"A: {A}")
print(f"B: {B}")

A = push_to_stream(A, stream)
B = push_to_stream(B, stream)
C = push_to_stream(np.zeros([10]).astype(np.float32), stream)

size = np.array(10, dtype=np.uint64)
n_threads = np.array(NUM_BLOCKS*NUM_THREADS, dtype=np.uint64)

def get_ptr(x):
    return np.array(int(x), dtype=np.uint64)

A_ptr = get_ptr(A)
B_ptr = get_ptr(B)
C_ptr = get_ptr(C)

args = [
    A_ptr, B_ptr, C_ptr, size, n_threads
]
# args must be void**
args = np.array([arg.ctypes.data for arg in args], dtype=np.uint64)

err, = cuda.cuLaunchKernel(
    KERNEL,
    NUM_BLOCKS,  # grid x dim
    1,  # grid y dim
    1,  # grid z dim
    NUM_THREADS,  # block x dim
    1,  # block y dim
    1,  # block z dim
    512,  # dynamic shared memory
    stream,  # stream
    args.ctypes.data,  # kernel arguments
    0,  # extra (ignore)
)
cuda_check(err)

### --- DONE preparing parameters --- ###

### --- launching the kernel --- ###

out = np.zeros( [10] ).astype(np.float32)
err, = cuda.cuMemcpyDtoHAsync(
    out.ctypes.data, C, byte_size(out), stream
)
cuda_check(err)

err, = cuda.cuStreamSynchronize(stream)
cuda_check(err)

print(f"C (A+B): {out}")

### --- DONE launching the kernel --- ###

### --- cleaning up --- ###

def cleanup(memory_locs, stream):
    err, = cuda.cuStreamDestroy(stream)
    cuda_check(err)
    for m in memory_locs:
        err, = cuda.cuMemFree(m)
        cuda_check(err)

cleanup([A,B], stream)

err, = nvrtc.nvrtcDestroyProgram(PROGRAM)
cuda_check(err)
err, = cuda.cuModuleUnload(MODULE)
cuda_check(err)
err, = cuda.cuCtxDestroy(CONTEXT)
cuda_check(err)
```

After running it, I get the following output:

```
UTF-8
ANSI_X3.4-1968
compilation of NVRTC successful, ptx size 1343
A: [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
B: [9. 8. 7. 6. 5. 4. 3. 2. 1. 0.]
C (A+B): [9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9. 9.]
```

The first two lines show how the preferred encoding has changed.

If I try to check which are the *current* and the *default* locales, I can see that they are still reported to be UTF-8 and I found no easy way to change the *preferred* locale with other functions from the `locale` library.

For reference, take a look at the output of the following code before and after calling the nvrtc:

```py
import os 
import locale

print(locale.getdefaultlocale())
locale.resetlocale()
print(locale.getpreferredencoding(False))
print(locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_CTYPE))
! env | grep LC
locale.localeconv()
```

before:

```
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
UTF-8
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=C
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
{'int_curr_symbol': 'USD ',
 'currency_symbol': '$',
 'mon_decimal_point': '.',
 'mon_thousands_sep': ',',
 'mon_grouping': [3, 3, 0],
 'positive_sign': '',
 'negative_sign': '-',
 'int_frac_digits': 2,
 'frac_digits': 2,
 'p_cs_precedes': 1,
 'p_sep_by_space': 0,
 'n_cs_precedes': 1,
 'n_sep_by_space': 0,
 'p_sign_posn': 1,
 'n_sign_posn': 1,
 'decimal_point': '.',
 'thousands_sep': ',',
 'grouping': [3, 3, 0]}
```

and after the compilation:

```
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
ANSI_X3.4-1968
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=C
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
{'int_curr_symbol': '',
 'currency_symbol': '',
 'mon_decimal_point': '',
 'mon_thousands_sep': '',
 'mon_grouping': [],
 'positive_sign': '',
 'negative_sign': '',
 'int_frac_digits': 127,
 'frac_digits': 127,
 'p_cs_precedes': 127,
 'p_sep_by_space': 127,
 'n_cs_precedes': 127,
 'n_sep_by_space': 127,
 'p_sign_posn': 127,
 'n_sign_posn': 127,
 'decimal_point': '.',
 'thousands_sep': '',
 'grouping': []}
```

you can see that the environment is still set to be in UTF-8 mode and that just the preferred encoding (and its conventions) are changed.

With this in mind, I wonder what is the difference between the *preferred* and *default* locales and if it is possible to change the first one in some way.

I am already aware that `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` under the hood calls `_locale.nl_langinfo(_locale.CODESET)` from the `_locale` library, which is a direct interface to the [`nl_langinfo(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nl_langinfo.3.html) function... If I call it from C within the same environment I get that the preferred encoding is still UTF-8, so I would guess that the effects of the change are somehow limited to the current python instance, with no effect outside of it.

Anyway, I think that I am not the first one having issues with how the default encoding is chosen for the `open` function as, luckily, it is going to be changed in [python 3.15](https://peps.python.org/pep-0686/).

Thank you all for the help and let me know if you need some other information.

System details:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

the code above was tested on both python 3.10.6 and 3.9.12

Comment: I suggest [filing an issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-python/issues).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I will surely do, but I am also interested in understanding in general if there is a way to operate on the preferred locale.

Comment: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-python/issues/29)

Comment: what does your `LANG` environment variable look like before and after running the nvrtc part/test?

Comment: en_US.UTF-8 in both cases

Comment: @RobertCrovella As you can see from the reply to the GitHub issue, it looks like this behaviour is caused by NVRTC itself. I have filed a bug to Nvidia now.

Comment: By discussing with Nvidia we found out that, exporting `LC_ALL=POSIX` in the environment is a workaround to have NVCC keep the UTF-8 encoding. The reasons behind the bug are however still unclear.

Comment: Link to the Nvidia bug report: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/3833924

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently a bug in nvrtc. As a workaround:

> Just to give a small update. By discussing the issue with Nvidia we
> found out that it is possible to export LC_ALL="POSIX" as a workaround
> to avoid NVCC changing the encoding to ASCII.

(Answer assembled from comments and added as community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag)

Comment: Note that the workaround has an important misunderstanding: Setting LC_ALL=POSIX will switch the whole program to ASCII encoding and also change the language.